# Unable to get JSON from String

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am getting the value of newDetails as a string.When I try the following code I get an exception as

> [__NSArrayI dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I have declared `newDetail` as an `NSString`. Also, the values of both `newDetail` in this and below code are same.
Here's the code:

```
newDetail = [response valueForKey:@"newDetail"];
//newDetail prints as {"number":1,"nid":"1","pId":"3","name":"","me":"","day":"1"}
        NSError *error;
        NSData* data = [newDetail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];
```

But when I try the below code, it runs perfectly:

```
newDetail = @"    {\"number\":1,\"nid\":\"1\",\"pId\":\"3\",\"name\":\"\",\"me\":\"\",\"day\":\"1\"}";       
        NSError *error;
        NSData* data = [newDetail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting an exception?

Comment: My guess would be that the value for the key "newDetail" isn't a string but some other data type. Possibly [NSNull null].

Comment: I am printing the value of newDetail, it's not null

Comment: And you're sure it's coming back as a string and not a dictionary? The line that's being printed out is ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: It' might be the `valueForKey:` trap. What happens using `response[@"newDetail"]`?

Comment: Is there any way around??

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the following code returns an `NSArray`:

```
newDetail = [response valueForKey:@"newDetail"];
```

I suspect this because of the error message, which states that you try to call the method `-dataUsingEncoding:` on a `NSArray` object.

But ... you mention it prints like:

```
{"number":1,"nid":"1","pId":"3","name":"","me":"","day":"1"}
```

Which would mean it's a NSDictionary (key/value pairs).

You could log the class to be sure like the following:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [newDetail class]);
```

Your version works because you hardcode a string. You should get the same error if you'd try to serialize a NSDictionary or perhaps even a NSArray into a JSON string, like this:

```
// This should result in the same error, since we serialize 
// an empty dictionary into a JSON string.
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:@{}
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];
```